# Proof by induction coins

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Question: Tom only have 2 type of coins: coins: 4 cents and 5 cents. Write a proof by induction that every amount n ≥ a can indeed be paid with Tom coins

1) Base Case: Tom can pay $12, $13, $14, $15, $16 and $17

2) Inductive steep: Let n>= 17 and suppose the Tom can pay every amount k with 12 <= k < n

3) Proof of claim: I am confused now...

edit: it's a normal induction, not strong induction

Comment: If you can get $k = a$ four cents and $b$ five cents, how con you do $k + 1$.  How many four cents and how many five cents would you need?

Comment: Hint:  $5-4 = 1$.  and $4*4 - 3*5 = 1$.

Comment: Oh coffee maths answer is better than my hint.   Dont try to go from $n= k$ to $n+1 = k+1$.  Go from $n= k-4$ to $n+5 = k+1$.

Comment: Is it for strong or normal induction? thank you!

Comment: The *only* difference between strong and weak is that with strong you use all lower values you've already done.  Not just the current one you are assuming.  There is no significant difference.  I really don't think strong is forbidden.  I just think the haven't yet taught you the term.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your next case where $n \ge 17.$ you can subtract $5$ and get $12$ (already done by earlier case.)
 If $n=18$ subtract $5,$ and so on up to $22.$ Keep going in such groups of six.

Answer (score 0):

Normal induction includes strong induction.

But consider this:

Assume $k = 4a + 5b$.

Case 1: $a > 0$ then $k+1 = 4a + 5b+1 = 4a + 5b + 5 -4 = 4(a-1) + 5(b+1)$.  Done.

Case 2: $a = 0$ but $k > 2$, then $k +1 =4a + 5b +1 = 4a + 5b + 16-15 = 4(a+4) + 5(b-3)$.  Done.

Case 3: $a = 0$ and $k \le 2$ then $k\le 10$ and ... that's not a concern.

======

This is a good example of *strong* induction.

Suppose you know you can do it for *ALL* cases $12 \le n \le k$.  And $k \ge 17$.  Then you can do it for $k-4$.  And if you can do it for $k -4$ you can do it for $k -4 +5 =k+1$ simply by doing what you did for $k-4$ and adding a $5$ cent coin.

Comment: Thanks @fleablood but I forgot to mention it's not strong induction, it's normal induction

Comment: Strong induction and regular induction are the same thing really.